# Apply to value to class inside def and send it to another val at another class

Tags: scala, class, object, call, send

Hope you are doing good, I just started a basic scala programming for creating API. So I have models product with the following code:

```
import.blablabla._
case class Product(prodId:Int, prodBig:int, prodPcs:Int, price:Int, resProd:Double)

object Product{
  def add(prodId:Int, prodBig:int, prodPcs:Int): Product = {
    Storage.cnts(prodBig, prodPcs)
    var resProd = ?????????
    val price = 4000
    val resJsn = Product(clientId, prodBig, prodPcs, price, resProd)
    Ok(Json.obj("result" -> resJsn)).withHeaders(
              AUTHORIZATION -> endtoken)
      }
```

and other class with the following code:

```
import.blablabla._
case class Storage (resProd: Double)    

    object Storage {
          def cnts(prodBig:Int, prodPcs:Int) {
            val prod = prodPcs/prodBig
            ??????????
          }
        }
```

My Question is:
How do I apply value of prod to resProd? and how do I apply the Storage (resProd) value to resProd at Product class?

I believe this could be easy to answer if you had experience with java or scala. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manually update `Storage.resProd` by calling `cnts`, I don't think it's a good idea. Companion object, `object Storage` in your code, is suitable for factory methods.

So I recommend
1. Create new Stroage in cnts:

```
def cnts(prodBig:Int, prodPcs:Int) {
    val prod = prodPcs/prodBig
    new Storage(prod)
}
```

2. Move cnts to class Storage:

```
case class Storage (var resProd: Double) {
   // some update method comes here
}
```

Comment: Hi Honey, thank you for your advice. Another question is how do I call the resProd value at Storage class to Product Object?

Comment: @DedenBangkit just call resProd `val prod = Storage.cnts(prodBig, prodPcs).resProd` because resProd is a public value here.